# HorizontalScrollView lagging

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've created an horizontal scroll view:

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrlVPrincipal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCard1"
            android:layout_width="259dp"
            android:layout_height="390dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.504"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.801" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCard2"
            android:layout_width="259dp"
            android:layout_height="390dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.8" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgCard3"
            android:layout_width="259dp"
            android:layout_height="390dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.8" />

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

The problem is, every time I scroll, it becomes too laggy and I can't use my app in a fluid form! I've read, in this site, that a ScrollView with many childs can become laggy. The images that I insert into my ImageViews aren't too heavy... Can you tell me what is causing this slowness?

Comment: Try loading smaller images for starters, and using RecyclerView...

Comment: In order to really get to the bottom of the specific issue, you would need to post the code that you're using to actually insert the images into those views. Generally speaking though, if you're creating a scrolling view of containers with images, `RecyclerView` would absolutely be the way to go - it's built for exactly this. You could also look at image loading libraries like Picasso.